# PyCharm ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_fontdata_enc_winansi'

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I have a PyCharm project that uses to other projects that are github checkouts managed as separate PyCharm projects.
I use a python script form one of the external projects(z3c.rml) and this script is dependent on the other external project(reportlab).
I have configured the src folders of the external projects as content root src folders in my project.
When I run the external script inside my project the script does not find the other external project sources.
PyCharm does not show any unresolved symbol errors in my project.

Running the script produces the following stacktrace:

```
E:\Users\Work\Documents\ReportConverter\python\win-venv\Scripts\python.exe E:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\z3c.rml\src\z3c\rml\rml2pdf.py rml/test/sample.rml ../data/sample.pdf 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\z3c.rml\src\z3c\rml\rml2pdf.py", line 24, in <module>
    from z3c.rml import document
  File "E:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\z3c.rml\src\z3c\rml\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import z3c.rml.paraparser
  File "E:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\z3c.rml\src\z3c\rml\paraparser.py", line 21, in <module>
    import reportlab.platypus.paragraph
  File "E:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\reportlab\src\reportlab\platypus\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Flowable, Image, Macro, PageBreak, Preformatted, Spacer, XBox, \
  File "E:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\reportlab\src\reportlab\platypus\flowables.py", line 34, in <module>
    from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth
  File "E:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\reportlab\src\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfmetrics.py", line 22, in <module>
    from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata
  File "E:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\reportlab\src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata.py", line 159, in <module>
    module = __import__(modname, globals(), locals())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_fontdata_enc_winansi'
```

I checked the python ans sys path in the python console

```
>>> print (os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/third_party/thriftpy;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev
import sys
print (sys.path)
['C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\\plugins\\python-ce\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\\plugins\\python-ce\\helpers\\third_party\\thriftpy', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\\plugins\\python-ce\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'E:\\Users\\Work\\Documents\\ReportConverter\\python\\win-venv', 'E:\\Users\\Work\\Documents\\ReportConverter\\python\\win-venv\\Lib\\site-packages', 'E:\\Users\\Work\\Documents\\ReportConverter\\docker', 'E:\\Users\\Work\\Documents\\ReportConverter\\python', 'E:\\Users\\Work\\PycharmProjects\\reportlab\\src', 'E:\\Users\\Work\\PycharmProjects\\z3c.rml\\src', 'E:\\Users\\Work\\Documents\\ReportConverter\\python\\py']
```

It seems all fine to me.

I tried in the python console:

```
>>>import _fontdata_enc_winansi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_fontdata_enc_winansi'

>>>import reportlab.pdfbase._fontdata_enc_winansi
```

That works fine.
It seems that python does not search from modules in subfolders like "reportlab.pdfbase"

The problem is: the modulename is generated but without the package folders:

```
    modname = '_fontdata_enc_%s' % keyname.lower()[:-8]  #chop off 'Encoding'
    module = __import__(modname, globals(), locals())
```

The searched module is located in the same package as the above code

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
 module = __import__(modname, globals(), locals(), level=1)
```

In opposition to the documentation you need to add "level=1" to the __import__ call in order to search locally for modules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).